# How can I resend a Devise confirmation email automatically, but only once, for users who have not confirmed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

I am using Rails with Devise `confirmable`. When users sign up Devise automatically sends them a confirmation email. If they haven't confirmed after three days, I would like to send them another confirmation email with a new token. If they still do not confirm after this second email, we should send them no more. Mapped out on a timeline:

- **Day 1:** User signs up & receives confirmation email; does not confirm
- **Day 2:** User does not confirm
- **Day 3:** Send another email prompting them to confirm; does not confirm
- **Day 4:** User does not confirm; no more emails sent
- **Day 5:** User does not confirm; no more emails sent
- **Day 6:** etc.

I'd rather not add a new column to my Users model that keeps track of how many times they've been sent a confirmation email since I think I can do it in a Worker that runs every day using the information we already have. However I'm struggling a bit with getting the logic right.

Here's what I have so far:

```
# workers/resend_confirmation_worker.rb

class ResendConfirmationWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: :resend_confirmation, retry: false

  def perform
    users = User.where('confirmation_sent_at IS NOT NULL and
                        confirmed_at IS NULL')
    users.each do |user|
      return if user.created_at < Time.zone.now - 4.days || user.created_at > Time.zone.now - 3.days
      user.resend_confirmation!
  end
end

# config/clock.rb

module Clockwork
  every(1.day, 'Resend confirmation') { ResendConfirmationWorker.perform_async }
end
```

Appreciate any help or suggestions for improvement.

Comment: Use `.find_each` which loads the records in batches to avoid potentially exhausting the available memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = 2.days.ago
users = User.where.not(confirmation_sent_at: nil)
            .where(confirmed_at: nil)
            .where(created_at: d.beginning_of_day..d.end_of_day)

users.find_each do |user|
  user.resend_confirmation!
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to run the worker once a day, you could probably use something like:

```
User.where('
  confirmed_at IS NULL
  AND created_at >= ?
  AND created_at <= ?
', 2.days.ago.beginning_of_day, 2.days.ago.end_of_day)
```

If you run this on Wednesday, it fetches all unconfirmed users that are registered on Monday.

Answer (score 1):

The answer posted by [max](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41498017/1105159) is almost perfect however you need to use `user.send_confirmation_instructions` instead of `resend_confirmation!`, and if the worker ran more than once in a day by accident (e.g. due to a dyno restart), people could potentially get too many confirmation emails.

Now all I'm trying to figure out is [why my tests aren't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41517881/testing-that-devise-is-re-sending-confirmation-instructions-email-in-a-backgroun).